# Capistrano deployment fails when server ssh key has a passphrase

Tags: ssh, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean, ssh-keys

Deploying with Capistrano fails when I have a passphrase set for ssh keys on the remote server.

But it works when there is no passphrase set...

I would like to be able to input the password when deploying so that I can still use a passphrase on the server.

**Error:**

```
01 mkdir -p /tmp
01 <user>@<ip> 0.183s
Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-<app>-<env>-<me>.sh 100.0%
02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-<app>-<env>-<me>.sh
02 <user>@<ip> 0.178s
git:check

01 git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:<me>/<my-repo>.git
01 Permission denied (publickey).
01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
01
01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
01 and the repository exists.

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as <user>@<ip>: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.7.1'
set :application, '<app>'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:<me>/<app>.git'
set :user, '<user>'
set :scm_user, '<me>'
set :deploy_to, '/home/<user>/<app>'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle"
```

**deploy/production.rb**

```
server '<ip>', user: '<user>', roles: %w{app db web}
```

So I would like Capistrano to ask me for the password when deploying so that my server can use it to connect with github.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions on the Capistrano site?  http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/

Comment: Check out the section on 'SSH Agent Forwarding'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSH Agent Forwarding. So there's no need to enter a passphrase on the server.

This way you just preload your ssh key/s locally `ssh-add keyname_rsa` and have them automatically forward to your host, then from your host to the Github servers as necessary.

So you only enter your passphrase once locally like this:

[image]

And the rest happens "automagically" during deployment. It's worth setting up.

From [the docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/):

> 1.2.1 **SSH Agent Forwarding**
>
> As we’ve already set up an SSH agent, we can use the *agent forwarding*
>   feature of SSH to make this key agent available to further *hops*. In
>   short, we can use **our own ssh key** to authenticate ourselves from the
>   server to Github.